# Understanding intents in Android authentication

Tags: android, authentication, android-intent

I have a few doubts about the Android architecture when dealing with authentication.

Suppose I call `AccountManager.getAuthToken` for a particular account I need to authenticate. Let's say that authentication fails due to bad password. The `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` contract requires the authenticator to return a `Bundle` with the `Activity` that handles username/password input via `KEY_INTENT`.

My question is: who is supposed to show the UI? Does Android automatically detect that `KEY_INTENT` is present and run the UI or does my code have to `startActivity` with the intent embodied in the `AccountManager`'s response? The same applies to `AccountManager.addAccount` which bundles the result through a Future interface.

Where can I find some tutorials on these topics?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system doesn't automatically show the activity when `KEY_INTENT` is present.
It's up to you to start that activity.

Here's some sample code:

```
private AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> mAccountManagerCallback = new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {

        Bundle bundle;
        try {

            bundle = future.getResult();
            //if an intent was sent, start the required activity
            if (bundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT)) {
                Intent intent = bundle.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);

                //clear the new task flag just in case, since a result is expected
                int flags = intent.getFlags();
                flags &= ~Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
                intent.setFlags(flags);

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTH);

        } else {
            //otherwise, just get the credentials
            if (bundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN)) {
                    String authToken    = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                    String userMail     = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    //use the credentials
            }
        }
      }
      catch(...) {
        ...
        //handle errors, maybe retry your getAuthToken() call
      }
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for, but in case I did not understand your question correctly, please clarify.

Cheers!

Comment: What if I'm **not** using a callback? I asked the question because I want to know if and what the UI has to do in case an Intent is returned by the authenticator. Does the system show it up automatically or do I have to implement the code in the caller? I'm starting to think that only the system can run the intent because it must run with the same UID as the account creator. I'm really confused

Comment: [Add] I guess your first sentence *is* the answer: every caller must implement all the logic...